# C programming, unable to get field from siginfo

Tags: c, signals

I want to access - _addr residing in _sigfault which is part of siginfo structure. siginfo structure defined in asm-generic/siginfo is as follows -

```
typedef struct siginfo {
        int si_signo;
        int si_errno;
        int si_code;

        union {
                int _pad[SI_PAD_SIZE];

                /* kill() */
                struct {
                        pid_t _pid;             /* sender's pid */
                        __ARCH_SI_UID_T _uid;   /* sender's uid */
                } _kill;

                /* POSIX.1b timers */
                struct {
                        timer_t _tid;           /* timer id */
                        int _overrun;           /* overrun count */
                        char _pad[sizeof( __ARCH_SI_UID_T) - sizeof(int)];
                        sigval_t _sigval;       /* same as below */
                        int _sys_private;       /* not to be passed to user */
                } _timer;

                /* POSIX.1b signals */
                struct {
                        pid_t _pid;             /* sender's pid */
                        __ARCH_SI_UID_T _uid;   /* sender's uid */
                        sigval_t _sigval;
                } _rt;

                /* SIGCHLD */
                struct {
                        pid_t _pid;             /* which child */
                        __ARCH_SI_UID_T _uid;   /* sender's uid */
                        int _status;            /* exit code */
                        clock_t _utime;
                        clock_t _stime;
                } _sigchld;
                /* SIGILL, SIGFPE, SIGSEGV, SIGBUS */
                struct {
                        void *_addr; /* faulting insn/memory ref. */
#ifdef __ARCH_SI_TRAPNO
                        int _trapno;    /* TRAP # which caused the signal */
#endif
                } _sigfault;

                /* SIGPOLL */
                struct {
                        __ARCH_SI_BAND_T _band; /* POLL_IN, POLL_OUT, POLL_MSG */
                        int _fd;
                } _sigpoll;
        } _sifields;
} siginfo_t;
```

I am unable to access _addr field. Following is the code i wrote for accessing it - 
siginfo_t sigInfo.
printf("%x",sigInfo._sifields._sigfault._addr);

Error i get during compilation is - 
sampleTrace.c: In function 'main':
sampleTrace.c:12: error: 'struct ' has no member named '_addr'

Can you please suggest what wrong am i doing here?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `si_addr`, as described by [`signal.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html).

> The `<signal.h>` header shall define the siginfo_t type as a structure,
>   which shall include at least the following members:
>
> ```
> /* ... */
> void         *si_addr   Address of faulting instruction.
> ```

Try:

```
siginfo_t *info;
/* ... */
printf("%x", info->si_addr);
```

Comment: Now there's a quantum leap - without specific knowledge of signal(), how would someone ever find that?

Comment: i am not sure what u r asking Kevin. If u are asking about the signal received by the process than that can be obtained by looking at the first member of the siginfo - si_signo.